# Can an HTTP request be uniquely identifiable?

Tags: http, get, request, httprequest

I've heard mention of an algorithm that can identify a unique user by parsing header information in an HTTP GET request. I'm curious - what combination of data points in an HTTP request would uniquely identify a client? (assuming this is NOT referring to an IP address).

Comment: I've only seen this done with cookies that drop a uuid/random number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you mean this? http://panopticlick.eff.org/index.php?action=log&js=yes